# Rounding off dates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am working on dates and got the requirement in this way.
In case the recruit date is between 1st - 7th day of the month (e.g. July 3 2014), then the recruit date should be July 1 2014.
In case the recruit date is after the 7th day of the month (e.g. July 8, 2014. Recruit date should be on the following month Aug 1 2014.
So, I prepared an SQL, using add months and round, but it is not giving me desired results. Could you please help me modify the query

```
SELECT AST.X_REC_DT,
CASE
WHEN (to_char(AST.X_REC_DT, 'DD') <= 7)
THEN ROUND(to_date(add_months(AST.X_REC_DT, -1)))
when (to_char(AST.X_REC_DT, 'DD') > 7)
then ROUND(to_date(add_months(AST.X_REC_DT, 1)))
END AS RTD
FROM EMPLOYEE AST WHERE AST.ROW_ID = '1-EWR'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for any complicated case statements, just use this code:

```
select trunc(add_months(ast.x_rec_dt,1)-7,'mm') RTD
  from employee ast
 where ast.row_id = '1-EWR';
```

It first adds one month to the date in question, then subtracts 7 days from the new date, then truncates the whole thing to the beginning of the month.

Comment: Nice, logic beats SQL. :) But what is the `EWR` stuff?

Comment: @GergelyBacso the `1-EWR` stuff came for the OP's question.

Comment: @Sentinel : Fantastic. Thanks a lot ! Didn't think through that angle :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` statement to see if the date is on or before the 7th day of the current month.  If it is not, add a month.  This logic will show you how that works using all the dates in 2016 as test data.

```
WITH dates AS
       (SELECT TO_DATE ('01-JAN-2016') + ROWNUM - 1 dte
        FROM   DUAL
        CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 365)
SELECT dte,
       -- This is the logic you want right here:
       CASE WHEN dte <= TRUNC (dte, 'MM') + 7 - 1 THEN TRUNC (dte, 'MM') ELSE TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (dte, 1), 'MM') END
         modified_dte
FROM   dates;
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, I used TRUNC in my query  as well and it solved the purpose. SELECT AST.X_REC_DT,
CASE
WHEN (to_char(AST.X_REC_DT, 'DD') <= 7)
THEN TRUNC (TO_DATE (add_months(AST.X_REC_DT, 0)), 'MONTH')
when (to_char(AST.X_REC_DT, 'DD') > 7)
then TRUNC (TO_DATE (add_months(AST.X_REC_DT, +1)), 'MONTH')
END AS RTD
FROM EMPLOYEE AST WHERE AST.ROW_ID IN ('1-EWR', '1-ATL') Thanks for your awesome help as always !

Answer (score 1):

This one works:

```
select recruit_date,
    case 
       when EXTRACT(day FROM recruit_date) <= 7 then trunc(recruit_date, 'MM')
       else ADD_MONTHS(trunc(recruit_date, 'MM'),1)
    end converted_date
from test;
```

It uses only three simple functions:

- trunc (truncates date to day by default, but can be parametrized if needed as you see above)
- add_months (adding months)
- extract (extracting specifc date values)